# Can I create a new script and chmod it in one command?

Tags: command-line, bash

When writing answers on here, it's often necessary to create a new script and `chmod +x` it to make it executable. I won't go into whether this is a good thing or not, but explaining to people that they need to fire in three separate command (and teaching them to use `nano`!) is a bit of a waffle.

Is there anything easier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why yes there is! Let me introduce you to the `install` command. `install` is a GNU-standard application that lets you copy files around and specify certain things at the same time. The short syntax is `install SOURCE DESTINATION`.

However, "certain things" are important. You can specify the file mode with `-m xxx` (755 for writeable by owner and executable by anyone). And bash has a couple of tricks for redirecting new files and here-doc for accepting long-form data. Here's a quick example:

```
install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin ~/testbin << EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo "Success!"
EOF
```

Now you can run `~/testbin` and it should echo out.

You can combine this with `sudo` for root-owned files or if you want to write as somebody else, you can sudo and use `install`'s `-o` owner flag.

The `-b` flag just creates a backup if you run the command a second time. This is helpful if you're doing potentially destructive tasks.