# How to automatically execute a command every time a certain command terminates?

Tags: command-line, apt, execute-command

Example: Once the `add-apt-repository` process has terminated, immediately run `apt-get update` - without having to enter the command manually.

Is there a way to do this? Is it possible to set such a combination without the use of the `sudo` password? (although I don't mind either way)

I'm asking the following: **How can I link two commands together, so that whenever I execute a particular command, it *always* executes the the linked command after it?**

Comment: You do know how to make a script?

Comment: Refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500071/running-a-sh-to-execute-multiple-commands) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334941/how-to-combine-multiple-commands-in-terminal)

Comment: You don't understand my question: **How can I link two commands together, so that whenever I execute a particular command, it *always* executes the the linked command after it?**

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "link"? It seems to me that what you want is a new command that calls the first, on success it calls the second, on success then maybe a third and so on.

Comment: @dadexix86 one command calls the other. That's it.

Comment: It would have helped a lot if you'd explain *why* you want it and what is the context. You simply leave people guessing a solution to an unclear problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various issues hooking into this with an alias or a simple bash function, but you can write a little wrapper for a command and stick it in `/usr/local/bin` which takes priority in your path.

This is a [little trick to create a script and chmod it at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/a/274650/449).
It'll dump an executable wrapper script in `/usr/local/bin/add-apt-repository`.

```
sudo install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin /usr/local/bin/add-apt-repository << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository "$@"
apt-get update
EOF
```

To reverse this, just delete `/usr/local/bin/add-apt-repository`.

If you want to do something fruitier (like linking `apt-get install` and `apt-get update` so you always update before installing), we just need to expand the script to look at the arguments.

```
sudo install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin /usr/local/bin/apt-get << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "install" ] ; then
    /usr/bin/apt-get update
fi
/usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
EOF
```

Though consider that this will run an update before *every* `apt-get install` call. This might sound helpful but could be really tedious in practice.

Comment: What if I chose another command, such as `apt-get install`? do I just replace the `add-apt-repository` bit?

Comment: `apt-get install` is not a command, it's a command and an argument. You can supplant `apt-get` in a similar way to this (save a script as `/usr/local/bin/apt-get` and have it call `/usr/bin/apt-get`) but your logic for calling things based on the arguments will be different from this script.

Comment: how about ~/.local/bin ?

Comment: @xiaodongjie Nope. `~/bin/` and `~/.local/bin/` aren't in the path for the sudo environment.

Comment: of course, but the script's contents includes sudo command in ~/.local/bin. @Oli

Comment: Assuming `sudo` is a potentially dangerous thing to do, especially for commands like Apt's that can be run usefully as both root and normal users. More than anything, you're suggest doing it here *just* so we can put the file somewhere else. That's a silly rationale.

Comment: Yes, i understand.

Comment: @geirha I think quoting the `$@` means the original arguments will be parsed as a single argument by the internal command. This is not desirable. Edit: this still seems to work so who knows.

Comment: `"$@"` expands all arguments as separate arguments. `"$*"` expands all arguments as a single argument (using the first character of `IFS` as separator). Using either unquoted is always wrong, since that will cause the shell to do word-splitting and pathname expansion on the result of the expansion.

Answer (score 5):

As normally,

```
sudo bash -c "command1; command2"
```

If you want to run command2 only after command1 is successfully completed,
you can use as `&&` rather than `;`.

```
sudo bash -c "command1 && command2"
```

I'll use following command for your example.

```
sudo bash -c "add-apt-repository <repo> && apt-get update"
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute certain commands in a particular sequence shell scripting is used. All you have to do is - Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
And follow the steps - 
1. Type `gedit filename.sh` 
2. After entering this command a text editor will open, where you can type the required commands one on each line. For example,
 `sudo add-apt-repository` 
 `apt-get update` 
3. After typing all the commands, save and exit either by using GUI or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
4. Now you will return back to terminal. Run `sh filename.sh` on terminal and your commands will execute, provided there is no error in your commands.
Also, if you login from superuser account (root) you won't have to type `sudo` in your command.

Comment: Did you read any of the other answers and comments?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes I did. But I guess they were rather complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository <ppa_name> && sudo apt-get update
```

If the first command is finished successfully, the second will be run.