# How to make a command execute once a certain command terminates?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, execute-command

What I want to do: Whenever the `apt-get install` command is run and terminates, run another command immediately without any involvement on the user's part. In my case I want to run a script, but since I can substitute a command for that, a command would be preferable as an example.

By the way, I don't want to run a script that executes two commands, since it must then be manually executed, which is not what I want. The termination of the `apt-get install` command must prompt the execution of another command.

**NOTE:** This may seem like a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/702325/146980) question, and while I do have an answer, I want to make my intention clear in case there are any other possible solutions, while also clarifying my requirements to other potential viewers to this question.

## Edit:

**To clarify:** I am trying to get one command that runs two!
**Why?** I want to generate a file containing a list of all the installed dependencies and software on my distro, which is updated every time the `apt-get install` command is used.

Comment: Unclear?? I don't get it - the question is as clear as possible!

Comment: this question is clear, but it may well be a duplicate, though i cannot find one. I'll be posting an answer in a second

Comment: @Serg So why does it have two votes to close this question as being "Unclear"?

Comment: command 1 ; commmand 2 or command 1 && command 2 or command 1 || command 2 depending on what you want

Comment: Never mind... I'm going to have to delete this question. I just can't get to explain what I'm looking for... **:(**

Comment: @DEvRobot don't delete , try to improve the question

Comment: @DevRobot are you trying to get one command that runs two ?

Comment: @Serg YES I am =D

Comment: @devRobot OK, editing my answer in a second

Comment: All => EDIT to my question

Comment: @DevRobot posted an answer, doesn't use a script as you requested

Comment: A script doesn't matter, one that contains commmand 2 or command 1 && command 2 or command 1 || command is not wanted :)

Comment: @DevRobot so you want to run command2 regardless of how command1 exited, right ? command1 failed or not, still run command2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard part is parsing the arguments correctly. You can handle simple `apt-get install pkgname` cases easily, but as soon as you want to handle `apt-get -y install pkgname` in addition, you suddenly need a full fledged option parser.

Assuming the simple cases is ok enough, something like this wrapper script may suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
status=$?

if [[ $1 = install ]]; then
    read -rp 'Run this other thing too [Y/n]? ' ans
    if [[ ${ans:-y} = [Yy] ]]; then 
        other-thing
        exit # exit with other-thing's exit status.
    fi
fi

exit "$status" # exit with apt-get's exit status.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's couple of ways, depending on your intention.

Sequential execution can me done with `;` separator. It will be done in sequence, each command runs regardless for previous command's exit status. Example:

```
echo hello; printf "\n\n%s" WORLD
```

Conditional execution can be done with boolean operators `||` and `&&`.
With these, execution of the second program, depends on the exit status of first (first and second read left to right).

For `&&` the behavior is as such: `COMMAND1 && COMMAND2` , if `COMMAND1` successfully terminated, `COMMAND2` will run. You can remember this as "if left succeeds, the right will run; if left failed, right won't run"
    [ -f /etc/passwd ] && echo "/etc/passwd exists"

For `||` it's opposite "If left succeeds, right won't run; if left fails, right will run"

```
[ -d /etc/passwd ] || echo "/etc/passwd is not a directory"
```

To put these into one single command, there is couple of options. One obviously is script, but as you requested, you don't want a script. Alternative to that is **bash function** OR **alias**.

Bash function is preferred since you can pass arguments to them if you so desire.

In your specific case, you want `apt-get install` which may take multiple parameters

```
function installStuff
{
  apt-get install "$@"
  command2
}
```

Place that into your `.bashrc`, somewhere at the top, close `.bashrc` and run `source .bashrc`. Now you have a bash function that always runs `apt-get install` first, with any number of packages requested, and then immediately `command2`

Like so

```
installStuff package1 package2 package3
```

For conditional running of command2 , use the `&&` and `||` operators i've already mentioned.